# Eloquent subscribers with SystemDefaultsQoS missing messages

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I started building and testing (and blooming) one of my packages for eloquent. Compared to the same code in dashing, one of the subscribers seems to miss messages now (which I can see being communicated, using ros2 topic echo).
Did the `SystemDefaultsQoS` change between dashing and eloquent in a way that would justify this behaviour?

I am building the `system_modes` package in a Lubuntu 1804 development setup (ROS 2 from sources). The subscriber in question is this one: https://github.com/micro-ROS/system_modes/blob/master/system_modes/src/mode-monitor-node.cpp#L253-L255 which is missing single parameter events from events that come in bursts.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/336320/eloquent-subscribers-with-systemdefaultsqos-missing-messages/) by [Arne Nordmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/39498/arne-nordmann/) on ROS Answers with karma: 28 on 2019-10-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I upgraded my setup to latest Eloquent and configured the `ParameterEvent` subscriber in question with `rclcpp::ParameterEventsQoS()`, which solved the issue.

---

Originally posted by [Arne Nordmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/39498/arne-nordmann/) with karma: 28 on 2019-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0